# Populating calendar with data from Songkick

Tags: jquery, api

Question:

I have two pieces - ajax function that calls/displays data from Songkick and function for jQuery calendar, both of which right now show up separately from each other.

How can I populate calendar with data from Songkick?

All the code is here:

http://ilyasitnikov.com/calendar/calendar.html

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the ajax callback function to populate the events array you pass to the calendar.

Instead of doing:

`$("#calendar").append('<li><a href="' + entry.uri+'">'+entry.displayName +'</a></li>');`

You can do:

```
var events = Array();
$.each(data["resultsPage"]["results"]["event"], function(i, entry) {
    events.push({title: entry.displayName, start: entry.date});
});
```

And then use that when initializing the Calendar. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what goes where, though...can anyone help out a noob? Thank you :-)